# Python error when importing pdp, get_dataset, info_plots from pdpbox

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I was trying to import `pdp`, `get_dataset`, `info_plots` from `pdpbox` in a Jupyter Notebook, but got the following error. It is from `from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import inset_axes`. Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks.

```
/opt/conda/envs/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pdpbox/pdp.py in \<module>   ~~~
      1 
      2 from .pdp_calc_utils import _calc_ice_lines, _calc_ice_lines_inter, _prepare_pdp_count_data
----> 3 from .pdp_plot_utils import (_pdp_plot, _pdp_inter_three, _pdp_inter_one)
      4 from .utils import (_check_model, _check_dataset, _check_percentile_range, _check_feature,
      5                     _check_grid_type, _check_memory_limit, _check_frac_to_plot, _make_list, _expand_default,
~~~ /opt/conda/envs/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pdpbox/pdp_plot_utils.py in \<module> ~~~
     11 from sklearn.cluster import MiniBatchKMeans, KMeans
     12 from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.axes_divider import make_axes_locatable
---> 13 from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import inset_axes
     14 
     15  
~~~ /opt/conda/envs/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid1/inset_locator.py in \<module> ~~~
    139 
    140 
--> 141 class BboxPatch(Patch):
    142     @docstring.dedent_interpd
    143     def __init__(self, bbox, **kwargs):
~~~ /opt/conda/envs/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid1/inset_locator.py in `BboxPatch()` ~~~
    140 
    141 class BboxPatch(Patch):
--> 142     @docstring.dedent_interpd
    143     def __init__(self, bbox, **kwargs):
    144         """
~~~ /opt/conda/envs/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/docstring.py in `__call__(self, func)` ~~~
     38     def __call__(self, func):
     39         if func.__doc__:
---> 40             func.__doc__ %= self.params
     41         return func
     42  ~~~
> KeyError: 'Patch'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar situation (using python 3.9)

I was able to solve it by downgrading my python version to 3.7.15

Comment: Can you provide any more information? The question appears to use Python 3.7, so it's not clear how this answer would solve this.

Comment: Maybe there is a change in the python version so that he uses for e.g. 3.7.2 or something. I just mentioned that with 3.7.15 it works. If your get the same error with that exact version than it's some other problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Future warning**: you might want to be cautious with this package. As an alternative, `scikit-learn` 0.22 introduced the [`PartialDependenceDisplay`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.inspection.PartialDependenceDisplay.html).

Running this code:

```py
from pdpbox import get_dataset
test_titanic = get_dataset.titanic()
```

Does this:

```py
joblib.load(os.path.join(DIR, 'datasets/titanic/titanic_model.pkl'))
```

The [Python pickle documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) has a big warning at the top that says: "The `pickle` module is not secure. Only unpickle data you trust."  Best case: this is an oversight; Worst case: this package is malicious.

---

If you trust this package, you can get it running with these dependencies (Python 3.7, 3.8):

```bash
pip install matplotlib==3.1.1 scikit-learn==0.23.1 xgboost==1.3.3 PDPbox==0.2.1
```

```py
from pdpbox import info_plots, get_dataset

test_titanic = get_dataset.titanic()
titanic_data = test_titanic['data']
titanic_target = test_titanic['target']
fig, axes, summary_df = info_plots.target_plot(
    df=titanic_data, feature='Sex', feature_name='Sex', target=titanic_target)
```

[image: Screenshot of a target_plot in a Jupyter notebook, plotting categories sex0 and sex1 with respect to average survival.]